# Custom gradle plugin with pmd, checkstyle and findbugs configured

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Thanks for the advice, in the doc it says:

```
TextResource ruleSetConfig

Note: This property is incubating and may change in a future version of Gradle.
The custom rule set to be used (if any). Replaces ruleSetFiles, except that it does not currently support multiple rule sets. See the official documentation for how to author a rule set. Example: ruleSetConfig = resources.text.fromFile(resources.file("config/pmd/myRuleSets.xml"))
```

But if I try

`setRuleSetConfig(project.resources.text.fromFile(project.resources.file("pmd.xml")))`

it says:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.resources.DefaultResourceHandler.file() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [pmd.xml]
Possible solutions: find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), with(groovy.lang.Closure), wait()
    at com.barista_v.android_quality.MyPmdTask.<init>(MyPmdTask.groovy:20)
    at com.barista_v.android_quality.MyPmdTask_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:121)
    ... 82 more
```

Also I am trying in this way::smile:

```
class MyPmdTask extends Pmd {

  MyPmdTask() {
    project.extensions.pmd.with {
      reportsDir = project.file("$project.buildDir/outputs/")
    }

    source = project.fileTree('src/main/java').toList()
    ruleSets = []
    reports {
      xml.enabled = false
      html.enabled = true
    }

    setIgnoreFailures(true)
    setRuleSetConfig(ResourceUtils.readTextResource(project, getClass().getClassLoader(), "pmd.xml"))
  }
}


class ResourceUtils {
  static TextResource readTextResource(Project project, ClassLoader classLoader, String fileName) {
    println "reading config file $fileName"
    def inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)
    project.resources.text.fromString inputStream.text
  }
}
```

and it set the config file but it dont use my rules, dont crash but dont use my rules.
I tried setting in

```
    project.extensions.pmd.with {
  // HERE
    }
```

when I try `getRuleSetConfig()` it returns null but with `setRuleSetConfig()` appears to be setted but not used.

I dont want to create another repo just for configurations like here https://github.com/MovingBlocks/TeraConfig.

Related to: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-read-setup-resources-from-plugin-jar/13274/4

what can I do?

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to solve this problem? I want to do something similar

Comment: @GabrielHuff no good news, I dont have a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create a custom plugin that adds a PMD task of the built-in type, using a custom ruleset packaged in the plugin's `src/main/resources` directory; I'm using kotlin, but you can probably get the idea:

```
class BuildPlugin: Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        val android = project.extensions.getByType(BaseExtension::class.java)
        project.pluginManager.apply(PmdPlugin::class.java)
        project.extensions.getByType(PmdExtension::class.java).toolVersion = "5.5.2"
        project.tasks.register("pmd", Pmd::class.java) {
            it.source(android.sourceSets.getByName("main").java.sourceFiles,
                      android.sourceSets.getByName("test").java.sourceFiles,
                      android.sourceSets.getByName("androidTest").java.sourceFiles)
            it.ruleSetConfig = project.resources.text.fromUri(javaClass.classLoader.getResource("config/pmd.xml"))
        }
    }
}
```

It's still a work in progress (for instance, I'm unsure if there are implications to resolving the android extension directly in my `apply`), but it seems to use my ruleset as expected!